# AWS / VPC Multiple Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Thanks for your time in advanced!

I am trying to setup some infratstructe in AWS / VPC that utilises a Dev, Test and Prod environment. Everything is complete expect for the networking side in the cloud that I cannot seem to get working. Essentially I will be running the 3 env's on one machine but host the services on the same port but independent IP's. I will then use DNS to talk to the different services / environments.

My questions / comments are as follows:

1. Can VPC / AWS Support 3 Public IP addresses in one instance (m3.medium)
2. Do I need three separate interfaces on the host or can I have one interface hosting multiple private addresses for the 1 to 1 NAT mapping.
3. Do you have any instructions for setting these interfaces up. I can get the interfaces up and running?

Strangely, I can get all the private interfaces up and running, I can get apache and the other services to bind to the private IP addresses but externally those new services dont work on anything other than SSH. Is this a firewall restriction or something on the instance or do I need a bigger, more expensive instance.

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What you try is very unusual for an AWS environment. In general all services should be separated on different machines. From the security perspective it is important to have Dev, Test and Prod seperated. Only this way the services can be protected by SecurityGroups or Network ACLs.

I would suggest to separate the services and suffer from the resulting advantages. To safe money you can shut down not needed instances and even use spot instances. This more standard setup is less error prone and much more easier to implement and support.